# How to use AVX2 in MASM/VS15?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, avx2

problem: I write something like this (inside proc):

```
.CODE
myProc PROC
    vpmovsxbd ymm0, qword ptr [rdx] ; rdx is ptr to array of 8 bytes
    vcvtdqps ymm0, ymm0
    ret
myProc ENDP
```

and masm complains with `invalid instruction operands` for first and `syntax error : ymm0` for second.
I'm compiling for x64 using VS15 community edition.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason to use asm then consider using intrinsics, e.g. `_mm256_cvtepi8_epi32`/`_mm256_cvtepi32_ps` in this particular case.

Comment: @PaulR well the thing I'm trying to write has to be specifically in asm.

Comment: OK - commiserations then. Note however that if this is for something performance-critical then you probably want to avoid putting stuff like this in functions as per above - you really want to inline your code as much as possible, at least for the innermost loops.

Comment: Why not use NASM instead of MASM?

Comment: @PaulR, the OP can't inline assembly in Visual Studio 64-bit mode. VS does not allow it. That's why MS pushes intrinsics so much and have intrinsics to do things most other compilers would do with inline assembly. The counter argument is this is why to use other compilers because MS has not created an intrinsic for everything you need from assembly.

Comment: @Zboson: sorry, I probably wasn't very clear - based on the OP's comments I'm assuming there's a whole bunch of other asm code involved here, so by "inlining" in this context I meant use asm macros for chunks of code such as the above example, rather than putting everything into subroutines and incurring call/return overhead.

Comment: @Zboson it's a study project I'm doing and the requirement is to use VS15 + masm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error looks like a problem in MASM--it simply refuses to accept that form of that instruction (even though the Intel docs say it exists).

The closest workaround I've been able to find is something like:

```
vmovdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr[rdx]
vpmovsxbd ymm0, xmm0
```

...but this is obviously kind of clumsy by comparison (since it destroys some xmm register, and obviously requires decoding an instruction instruction, etc.) On the other hand, it probably won't make much difference in speed as a rule (since the speed will usually be dominated by the memory read time in any case).

As a side note, the MS compiler seems to have roughly the same problem. A quick check using the `_mm256_cvtepi8_epi32` intrinsic, which Intel says *should* generate a `vpmovsxbd`, shows that the Microsoft compiler generates it like the sequence above--a `vmovdqu` followed by a `vpmovsxbd`.

For the second one, you apparently wanted `vcvtdq2ps`, but left out the `2`. Since the assembler didn't recognize that as an instruction, it got confused about what that line was supposed to be at all.

In case you actually care, it *probably* tried to parse it as a declaration like:

```
my_var dd ?
```

So, the first part (the `vcvtdqps`) seemed legitimate, but as a symbol, not an instruction. Then it found `ymm0` instead of something like `db`, `dw`, `dq` (etc.) and realized there was an error, because a register name wasn't a legitimate thing to have there.

Comment: `VEX.256.66.0F38.WIG 21

VPMOVSXBD ymm1, xmm2/m64
RM V/V AVX2 Sign extend 8 packed 8-bit integers in the low
8 bytes of xmm2/m64 to 8 packed 32-bit
integers in ymm1`
I wanted to use second instruction. Thanks - second one is fixed.

Comment: `vmovdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr[rdx]`
should be
`vmovdqu xmm0, qword ptr[rdx]`
in my case though.